# Termstore / managed metadata / content types

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, managed-metadata, term-store

SP2013 with SQL server 2014 environment.  I have never used the term store before and experimented a bit with Managed Metadata - so I need advice how / what to setup for my client please?
**Question 1:**
Document center can have two types of documents: DCdocuments (columns: Classification, Requester) and Client Case Files (inherit from DCDocuments with an extra column)
So when I upload a document in my library, it ask to complete the necessary fields specified in my content type.
In the library I then want to apply Key Filters, based on the columns created in my content type.

> *For example* I want to filter on 'Classification' (which is a drowdown field)  But when I go to managed metadata in library settings, it does not give me the option to select the field 'Classification'.  Why is that?
>   Or do I need to look at TermSets and Terms?

**Question 2:**
Client will upgrade to SP2016 within the next few months.  Will the managed metadata services or termstore setup make the migration difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer 1 : To be able to add column as filter type in managed metadata liberary settings you have first to create termset in managed metadata term store then create column as managed metadata field reference to TermSet.

Answer 2 : regarding to upgrade/migrations for managed metadata there is no any difficulties for make sure you can check

[Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0)